# can't set backgroundImage in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

Hey Guys I'm trying to build my portfolio site , I want to make the main page of the portfolio have a back ground image and when I navigate to other parts of the portfolio the background is just color , I handled setting the backgroundColor successfully but can't do the backgrounImage correctly .
Here is my code.

```js
  componentDidMount(){
      this.props.changePage("Main Page");
      document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('background.jpg')";
  }
```

that's the code inside the main page component but there seems to be something wrong , is it a problem with the syntax itself or the approach itself is wrong ?

EDIT 1!!

that's the code I used for backgroundColor and it's working why isn't it working with the backgroundImage .

```js
  componentDidMount(){
      this.props.changePage("About Me");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='black';
  }
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered without more details. Try adding more details or provide a reproducible example using CodeSandbox or similar.

Comment: This is the repo on git hub , I'd be really thankful if you would check it out 
 https://github.com/Lina-Basuni/Portfolio

Answer (score 1):

Set the className of element where you want to display your image equal to `.bgImage`.In CSS file(named as App.css) write down the code as given below that targets `.bgImage` and sets its background to the URL or Path provided  and import the CSS file in your main file using `import './App.css';`

```css
.bgImage {
  background: url(./media/hero.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  //some other properties 
}
```

Comment: I already tried something similar to that but the thing is I need the background to be dynamic and doing that sets the background statically .
This is the repo on git hub : https://github.com/Lina-Basuni/Portfolio

Comment: Do you want background to change on the same page after some time or the background should change on different page?

Comment: I want it to change on a different page

Comment: I have 4 pages I want each page to have a different background , I managed to do that with the backgroundColor property but couldn't do it with the backgroundImage property

Comment: Since you have 4 different pages, Try this thing, Set the className different in each page  where  you want to display image (eg  on page 1 set it equal to `.bgImage1` and on second page set it equal to `.bgImage2` and so on) then in CSS file target these classes separately i.e set the background property in `.bgImage1`  equal to  ` background: url(./media/hero1.jpg)`  and then set the  background property in `.bgImage2`  equal to  ` background: url(./media/hero2.jpg)`  and same for all of 4 image elements & then just import the CSS file.This should solve your problem. Thank you

Comment: i got it @HadiMir

Answer (score 1):

Your background image is in the wrong directory for create-react-app. Move `./src/background.jpg` to `./public/background.jpg`.